# dbGetQuery returns character classes instead of Date or POSIXlt

Tags: r, r-dbi

If I read out a field of type "datetime" it returns a character vector. Is it the genral way or do I have to notice something? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090082/handling-field-types-in-database-interaction-with-r) post came up with a similar question.

Comment: Based on the question you linked to, I suppose you're using MySQL and the R package RMySQL, but why you failed to include that information explicitly in your question is beyond me. Don't you _want_ help?

Comment: @joran I use RJDBC and that uses the DBI package for calls like dbGetQuery, so I suggest that this call is independent from the driver.

Comment: Well, see, that's pretty relevant information. Different drivers handle data type conversion differently.

Comment: You are right, sry but from there on, what should I do now? I want to know if its possible to get a POSIXlt vector instead of character vector.

Comment: My guess would be no, but I don't have any experience with RJDBC. I don't think that DBI does any conversion itself; all the other db interfaces I've used from R (RODBC, ROracle and RSQLite) do some attempt at conversion, but I don't know what, if anything RJDBC does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the DBI vignette (`vignette("DBI")`), Chapter 4 ("Data Type Mappings"), it states

> By default dates and date-time objects are mapped to character using
>   the appropriate TO_CHAR function in the DBMS (which should take care
>   of any locale information).

I can't find any suggestion that RJDBC overrides this behaviour, so you'll have to manually convert your dates.  Take a look at `strptime`, or the wrappers in the `lubridate` package.