# R assign variable types to large data.frame from vector

Tags: r, class

I have a wide `data.frame` that is all character vectors (`df1`).  I have a separate `vector`(`vec1`) that contains the column classes I'd like to assign to each of the columns in `df1`.

If I was using `read.csv()`, I'd use the `colClasses` argument and set it equal to `vec1`, but there doesn't appear to be a similar option for an existing `data.frame`.

Any suggestions for a fast way to do this besides a loop?

Comment: How did you wind up with this data.frame with all character values? Sounds like there may be a better way not to loose the data type information in the first place.

Comment: @MrFlick: data is coming thru a flat file via fread().  It was purposely read in as character due to id columns with leading zeroes.

Comment: You could use something like done here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090082/handling-field-types-in-database-interaction-with-r This is looping though, so probably not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it will be of help but I have run into the same need many times and I have created a function in case it helps:

```
reclass <- function(df, vec){
  df[] <- Map(function(x, f){
    #switch below shows the accepted values in the vector
    #you can modify it and/or add more
    f <- switch(f,
                as.is  = 'force',
                factor = 'as.factor',
                num    = 'as.numeric',
                char   = 'as.character')
    #takes the name of the function and fetches the function
    f <- get(f)
    #apply the function
    f(x)
  },
      df,
      vec)
df
}
```

It uses `Map` to pass in a vector of classes to the `data.frame`. Each element corresponds to the class of the column. The length of both the dataframe and the vector need to be the same.

I am using `switch` as well to make the corresponding classes shorter to type. Use `as.is` to keep the class the same, the rest are self explanatory I think.

Small example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(1:10, letters[1:10], runif(50))
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ X1.10        : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ letters.1.10.: Factor w/ 10 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ runif.50.    : num  0.0969 0.1957 0.8283 0.1768 0.9821 ...
```

And after the function:

```
df1 <- reclass(df1, c('num','as.is','char'))
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ X1.10        : num [1:50] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ letters.1.10.: Factor w/ 10 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ runif.50.    : chr [1:50] "0.0968757788650692" "0.19566105119884" "0.828283685725182" "0.176784737734124" ...
```

I guess Map internally is a loop but it is written in `C` so it should be fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try this function that makes the same work.

```
reclass <- function (df, vec_types) {
        for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
          type <- vec_types[i]
          class(df[ , i]) <- type
          }
        return(df)
        }
```

and this is an example of vec_types (vector of types):

```
vec_types <- c('character', rep('integer', 3), rep('character', 2))
```

you can test the function (reclass) whith this table (df):

```
table <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10,30, replace = T), nrow = 5, ncol = 6))
str(table)  # original column types

# apply the function
table <- reclass(table, vec_types)
str(table)  # new column types
```